# Redirect php query with hash using htaccess regex

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, hash

I'm trying to redirect URLs with a half of MD5 part inside a PHP query and one base64 encoded string after a '#' symbol to a new directory using a .htaccess Rewrite Rule.

URL examples:

A) `/?7027fcbbc2a1ccb9#N61/vMSRNqYQBhb+DcaSfv2YGW1HiBbSpMUoSHrtxok=`

B) `/index.php?f9c4bb60426abaf9#RBmcvFnf5+wFwP54IM8f7pUSvmPn2aOFm1Z6LbIOFK8=`

The URL contains two parts:

1. A half MD5 hash (16 a-f and 0-9 hash)
2. Followed with one "#" then a base64 encoded string

I'm trying to ask if the URL containts the 16 alphanumeric chars, and if yes, I want to redirect the whole URL (including the #hash followed info) to a new directory.

I'm trying with this Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^\\?[a-f0-9]{16}$ /newdirectory/$1 [L]
```

But of course it doesn't work. What is the correct regex for the redirection? Thank you so much!

Comment: @anubhava Something like this: `http://example.com/?7027fcbbc2a1ccb9#N61/vMSRNqYQBhb+DcaSfv2YGW1HiBbSpMUoSHrtxok=`  and i want redirect to: `http://example.com/newdir/?7027fcbbc2a1ccb9#N61/vMSRNqYQBhb+DcaSfv2YGW1HiBbSpMUoSHrtxok=` Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your URL is actually a query string not request URI. You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-f0-9]{16}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /newdir/ [L,R=301,NE]
```